# Data in a condensed format

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need a library which would help me to save and query data in a condensed format (a mini DSL in essence) here's a sample of what I want:

**Update 1** - Please note, figures in the samples above are made small just to make is easier to follow the logic, the real figures are limited with `c# long` type capacity, ex:
`1,18,28,29,39,18456789,18456790,18456792,184567896`.

Sample Raw Data set: `1,2,3,8,11,12,13,14`

**Condensed Sample Data set:**
`1..3,8,11..14`

What would be absolute nice to have is to be able to present `1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` as `1..10-3`.

**Querying Sample Data set:**

Query 1 (get range):
`1..5` -> `1..3`

Query 2 (check if the value exists)
`?2` -> `true`

Query 3 (get multiple ranges and scalar values):
`1..5,11..12,14` -> `1..3,11..12,14`

I don't want to develop it from scratch and would highly prefer to use something which already exists.

Comment: So you want all consecutive sequences?

Comment: What is query 1 supposed to do exactly - calculate the intersection? What should happen if the intersection is fragmented or empty?

Comment: I do want everything matching the search criteria in a condensed format ideally. I will accept data in a raw format too as the results are always tiny comparing to the input data (thousands of values)

Comment: @harold Query 1 returns the set of data matching the search criteria being 'get me everything from 1 to 5 inclusive', which is 1..3 or 1,2,3 in a raw format.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter yes, I'm looking to replace large volumes of raw data with its condensed representation and query that data after. Performance isn't a primary concern for me.

Comment: A list (or tree) of intervals works, but here's a different idea: a zero-suppressed BDD, where if viewed as family of sets the sets are sets of bits (so a set represents an integer) and the family is effectively a set of integers. It supports the queries you need and more. The reason I'm mentioning it is that it *may* be more compact than a list of intervals - it depends on the data though. Can you give a more detailed description of "typical data"?

Comment: Are you looking for a machine-readable way to store this data on disk, or a human-readable way to input data by hand?

Comment: I don't care about the last, main thing for me is to condense the data while still keeping the ability to query it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas I've had over the days since I read your question. I can't be sure any of them really apply to your use case but I hope you'll find something useful here.

#### Storing your data compressed

Steps you can take to reduce the amount of space your numbers take up on disk:

- If your values are between 1 and ~10M, don't use a `long`, use a `uint`. (4 bytes per number.)
- Actually, don't use a `uint`. Store your numbers 7 bits to a byte, with the remaining bit used to say "there are more bytes in this number". (Then 1-127 will fit in 1 byte, 128-~16k in 2 bytes, ~16k-~2M in 3 bytes, ~2M-~270M in 4 bytes.)

This should reduce your storage from 8 bytes per number (if you were originally storing them as `long`s) to, say, on average 3 bytes. Also, if you end up needing bigger numbers, the variable-byte storage will be able to hold them.

Then I can think of a couple of ways to reduce it further, given you know the numbers are always increasing and may contain lots of runs. Which works best for you only you can know by trying it on your actual data.

- For each of your actual numbers, store two numbers: the number itself, followed by the number of numbers contiguous after it (e.g. `2,3,4,5,6` => `2,4`). You'll have to store lone numbers as e.g. `8,0` so will increase storage for those, but if your data has lots of runs (especially long ones) this should reduce storage on average. You *could* further store "single gaps" in runs as e.g. `1,2,3,5,6,7` => `1,6,4` (unambiguous as `4` is too small to be the start of the next run) but this will make processing more complex and won't save much space so I wouldn't bother.
- Or, rather than storing the numbers themselves, store the deltas (so `3,4,5,7,8,9` => `3,1,1,2,1,1`. This will reduce the number of bytes used for storing larger numbers (e.g. `15000,15005` (4 bytes) => `15000,5` (3 bytes)). Further, if the data contains a lot of runs (e.g. lots of `1` bytes), it will then compress (e.g. zip) nicely.

#### Handling in code

I'd simply advise you to write a couple of methods that stream a file from disk into an `IEnumerable<uint>` (or `ulong` if you end up with bigger numbers), and do the reverse, while handling whatever you've implemented from the above.

If you do this in a lazy fashion - using `yield return` to return the numbers as you read them from disk and calculate them, and streaming numbers to disk rather than holding them in memory and returning them at once, you can keep your memory usage down whatever the size of the stored data.

(I *think*, but I'm not *sure*, that even the [GZipStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx) and other compression streams will let you stream your data without having it all in memory.)

#### Querying

If you're comparing two of your big data sets, I wouldn't advise using LINQ's `Intersect` method as it requires reading one of the sources completely into memory. However, as you know both sequences are increasing, you can write a similar method that needs only hold an enumerator for each sequence.

If you're querying one of your data sets against a user-input, small list of numbers, you can happily use LINQ's `Intersect` method as it is currently implemented, as it only needs the *second* sequence to be entirely in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any off-the-shelf library that does quite what you want, but I'm not sure you need one.

I suggest you consider using the existing `BitArray` class.  If, as your example suggests, you're interested in compressing sets of small integers then a single `BitArray` with, say 256 bits, could represent any set of integers in the range `[0..255]`.  Of course, if your typical set has only 5 integers in it then this approach would actually expand your storage requirements; you'll have to figure out the right size of such arrays from your own knowledge of your sets.

I'd suggest also looking at your data as sets of integers, so your example `1,2,3,8,11,12,13,14` would be represented by setting on the corresponding bits in a `BitArray`.  Your query operations then reduce to intersection between a test `BitArray` and your data `BitArray`.

Incidentally, I think your example 2, which transforms `2 -> true`, would be better staying in the domain of functions that map sets of integers to sets of integers, ie it should transform `2 -> 2`.  If you want to, write a different method which returns a boolean.

I guess you'd need to write code to pack integers into `BitArrays` and to unpack `BitArrays` into integers, but that's part of the cost of compression.

Comment: In my raw data I have data in the range from 1 to 10M (with a median number being from 200K to 800K so bits probably won't work), an average string length of a raw data array is 20K symbols, a lot of number are just sequences (I didn't mark another scenario, whereby 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 can be presented as 1..10~3, that's why I felt so tempted to find some smart compression library...

Comment: Yeah, a lot of folk post examples on SO, then, on reading answers to their question, respond that the answer doesn't satisfy them because their example was misleading.  I'm going to downvote your question because it doesn't provide essential facts to people trying to help you, I'll remove my downvote when (if ?) you move the data in your comment into your question.

Comment: Mind editing it and I'll minus you up too for making wring guesses and getting pissed after that...:)